# Use scope variable and dynamic css in ngClass

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-class

I would like to use a scope variable and and set css dynamically within html.

```
<div ng-class="myClassScope, { 'dynamic-class': !ifIsNot }">
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I think I asked it. this does not work.

Answer (score 2):

It your myClassScope is intended to always be applied, use ng-class this way:

```
<div class="myClassScope" ng-class="{'dynamic-class': !ifIsNot }">
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
<div ng-class="{ 'dynamic-class': !myClassScope }">
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to use multiple ng-class directives, it won't work. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rwq91dg/)

In order to use two ng-class directives, you can nest the elements, or you can bind to the class attribute:

```
<div ng-class="test_one">
    <div ng-class="{ 'test_two': !test_two }">test_two</div>
</div>
<div class="{{test_one}}" ng-class="{ 'test_two': !test_two }">test_three</div>
```

Comment: no, myClassScope is in ctrl, scope.myClassScope = 'custom-class'

Comment: so you are trying to use both the boolean ng-class object and the class string? see my edit

Comment: class={{ test_one }} this really slows down the app

Comment: For me appying multiple classes works like so: <... ng-class="{'class1': scopeVarForClass1, 'class2': scopeVarForClass2}" ... >